# Couple questions about probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm teaching my self probability and got stuck on a few example problems.

A coin gets tossed 6 times in a row.
The probability that someone guesses all 6 right should be (1/2)⁶.
To calculate the chance of guessing at least one right I think I have to do F(6)-F(0).

Now the Problem says that 512 people are guessing, i have to calculate the probability that none guesses all 6 right (which should be (1/2)⁶ too?). Got stuck here and I don't know how to proceed.

To get the average number of people getting all 6 right it would just be 512*(1/2)⁶

*I'm new to this board so i don't know if its cool if i stuff a couple questions regarding the same topic in one. If this i not wanted I'll delete the rest and post another.*

I have 10 light bulbs, each one has a probability of 0,2 to give light for more than 100h. I want to calculate the probability of exact one burning for more than 100 hours.

Don't know how to approach this experiment. Is it possible to imagine this as a urn experiment without putting back, the balls have the value (0,1,1,..,1) so 10 digits with only 1 for more than 100hours and 0 for not?.

So i could solve it with binomial distribution with n = 10, k = 1 and p = 0.2?
Would a hyper-geometric distribution in this context make sense?

**And last:**

/edit Deleted this problem because it covers stuff i did not read about until now

Comment: Recall that $P[A] = 1-P[A^c]$ for general events $A$, and $P[A]P[B]=P[A \cap B]$ if $A$ and $B$ are independent.  I agree for the first problem that you could alternatively do it by assuming $X \in \{0, 1, ..., 6\}$ is the number of correct guesses, and $F_X(x) = P[X \leq x]$, so $P[X \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\} ]= F_X(6) - F_X(0)$, which ends up the same as the $P[A] = 1-P[A^c]$ formula.

Comment: the last one could be modelled using the poisson distribution.  The parameter for poisson distribution is $\lambda$, and it happens that $\lambda$ can be shown to be the expected value  -so in this case $\lambda=2$ - now find P(x = 2) using poisson distribution, with $|lambda=2$

Comment: This is actually 3 questions; and the more question you pack into a single one, the longer you'll wait for an answer (if it will ever come).

Comment: for your first question, split it into two cases - they guess all wrong, and they do not guess all wrong - that includes all cases - P(X = 0) + P(X > 0) = 1 so P(X>1) = 1 - P(0) = $1 - (1/2)^6$

Comment: In the first problem, if I understood this correct, the probability of one guessing nothing right is the same as 512 guessing nothing right? Or am I missing a step? Thanks for pointing out that I should do more topic, will do this as soon I'm back home